# Can I connect 12ga wire for a gas range to 10ga wire from the service panel?

Tags: electrical, oven

I am remodeling my kitchen right now.

Can I use the existing 10ga line which already been built and used in my house for an electrical range to hook up 14ga or 12ga wire for my new gas range?

Comment: I edited out the second question that you added after the answers were posted. Please [ask a new question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) in cases like this where the new part is not directly related to the original. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have the right configuration of conductors yes, you can use a wire bigger than necessary. Be sure to change the circuit breaker to match the circuit and receptacle required. 
Remember, you CANNOT have a "standard" 15 or 20 amp receptacle on a 30A breaker.

Comment: No @bib, that's not what I am saying nor is it correct. You certainly can have a 15A duplex on a 20A circuit since it is rated at 20A feed-thru. Code explicitly states you cannot have 15 or 20A receptacles on a 30A circuit regardless of wire size.

Comment: Good point. I overstated and will remove the comment

Answer (score 1):

Be careful,if the circuit had #10 wire it may have a 30 amp breaker. The wire size must be rated for the breaker. You cannot use 14 ga or 12 ga wire on a circuit equipped with a 30 amp breaker.

Comment: @speedy petey; sorry, I basically restated what you already said. I did not read your answer prior to entering mine.

Comment: No problem Jimmy. Plenty of folks do just this intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you removed an electric range and installed a gas range and wish to  magically transform the 220V outlet into a 110V outlet for the new range?
Only if you do the following: change out the breaker which feeds that circuit to one rated for the wire used or end termination -= in this case a 20 amp outlet - which would thus be 20 amp. breaker.  And only use one of the hot legs - was it a 4 wire run or three.  If it was a three wire run and you use the red line for the neutral and the white for the ground - color code the ends before you hook them up. - maybe even put a little note on tape the next guy that gets in that box and wonders "what the??".
 Remember the breaker should trip before the wire overheats: 20amp breaker will protect #12 #10, #8 etc.  but a 30amp breaker will not protect #12 wire.